# How to efficiently toggle table rows in a table with 5000+ entries?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9

I understand how to generally toggle tr's in a table based on selection using jQuery's hide() and show(). This used to work quite effectively with a few hundred rows. Now, I need it to work for 5000+ entries in the DOM. And it freezes the browser completely.

My searches took me to learningjquery.com [here](http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/05/now-you-see-me-showhide-performance)

There is a "Enabling/Disabling a stylesheet" method explained in it that is supposed to work like a charm. And it does, except that it works like a charm only on IE9, taking only a second (if that) to filter the rows. On chrome, it takes over 15-20 seconds for the same action.

My trouble is Chrome is used pretty extensively by people for whom this application is being built. Can someone suggest me how to make this solution work in Chrome, or alternatively suggest other ways to handle this scenario.

1. I have tried other options like .css('display', 'none'), .addClass() and .removeClass(), etc. Nothing seems to make it fast.
2. I have tried datatables, and although quite fast afterward, it takes forever to initially load this amount of data.

Update: Many thanks to @jfriend00 and @Ohgodwhy. Here's the final code I have which works across all browsers.

```
$('#tbl_product_details tbody tr').each( function() {
    var row = $(this);
    row.hasClass("tr_"+cust_id) ? row.removeClass("hide") : row.addClass("hide");
});
```

Although, as the accepted answer shows, it can be further improved by plain js and by getting the dom elements once on page load, I didn't need to do it. The code is already fast enough, and I would rather have jQuery code all around.

Comment: It is unclear what your exact problem is.  You have a table of 5000+ entries, but what exactly are you trying to hide and how do you identify the rows you need to hide?  The performance secret is probably in those details so we need to see the HTML and know how you identify which rows to hide and then and only then, can one propose code to attach that problem.

Comment: The inherit flaw with your design is that you're relying on client side processing to manage this onslaught of rows. What you need to be doing is leveraging the server to handle this load; by that, I mean the use of pagination. There's almost no reason (that I can think of -- feasibly) to need to show 5,000 rows at a time. Filtering, Searching, Sorting, Pagination -- This is the exact reason why the aforementioned is available. To answer your question  - [you can see how much faster adding/removing classes is than showing/hiding elements.](http://jsperf.com/showhide-vs-addclass)

Comment: @jfriend00, I identify the rows to show based on a select element. Each tr in the table has a class that looks like tr_{$cust_id}. And to toggle them, I do    $('#tbl_product_details tbody tr:not(.special_hide)').addClass('special_hide');
$('#tbl_product_details tbody tr.tr_'+cust_id+'').removeClass('special_hide');

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, I never show the thousands of rows at once. It is always up to a few hundreds. While I am open to server side processing, the time taken to actually show all the rows (if I wanted to) is in milliseconds, so I didn't think it was necessary to burden the server with a call every time a pagination or search request is sent. I only ever need to filter based on customer id. No other filter is needed

Comment: @Abhilash then to answer the question at hand, you can see in the link I provided how much faster adding/removing classes is than toggling the `display` of the element. Your solution is to add/remove classes if you don't want to make changes for paginating. If you do want to paginate, then there's plenty of tutorials out there on how to do it. Try one out, if you can't get it to work, make a new question.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, Thanks. The benchmarks I ran showed that the Enabling/Disabling a stylesheet method in the link I shared in the question is faster even than the addClass() and removeClass() method you suggest. As in, many many times faster and almost independent of the number of rows you have in the html. It had the same speed for 5k rows as it did for 50k. It's just that Chrome doesn't seem to agree and IE9 does. I would have preferred it the other way around. :-)

Comment: @Abhilash Which is why I didn't mention the stylesheet method. It's too iffy dependent on browsers whereas class toggling is basically the same throughout; however, mobile-browsers are always the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, it sounds like you want to show only rows that have a class `tr_+custom_id` and hide all other rows.

The keys to the performance here will be making sure that you iterate through all the rows no more than once per operation.  Right now, you're doing it at least twice on each operation. And, you could even make it faster by iterating once as the page loads and building an index in javascript where you can search it much faster than iterating through the DOM.

As the first simplification, you can replace this two pass scheme:

```
$('#tbl_product_details tbody tr:not(.special_hide)').addClass('special_hide');
$('#tbl_product_details tbody tr.tr_'+cust_id+'').removeClass('special_hide');
```

with this one pass sheme:

```
var custRow = "tr_"+cust_id;
$('#tbl_product_details tbody tr').each(function() {
    var item = $(this);
    if (this.className.indexOf(custRow) != -1) {
        item.removeClass("special_hide");
    } else if (this.className.indexOf("special_hide") == -1) {
        item.addClass("special_hide");
    }
});
```

If the rows themselves don't change, you could preload the list of rows just once into a persistent variable after the page loads:

```
var rowList = $('#tbl_product_details tbody tr');
```

And, then use this JS:

```
var custRow = "tr_"+cust_id;
rowList.each(function() {
    var item = $(this);
    if (this.className.indexOf(custRow) != -1) {
        item.removeClass("special_hide");
    } else if (this.className.indexOf("special_hide") == -1) {
        item.addClass("special_hide");
    }
});
```

It could be sped up more by removing the jQuery and substituting some less general purpose plain javascript code.

It could be sped up further by keeping an index in javascript of what rows are currently shown and which rows are a given id so you can just directly operate on the rows you need to operate on without having to examine every row and every class name.  It could likely be made very quick doing it this way.

Comment: This seems like an approach, but I am worried if we will make things worse than before. Total tr count = 5000. Before first cust selection, all tr's have a special_hide class. So when a customer is selected for the first time, the first line of code matches zero nodes, and the second line of code matches (say) 100 rows. For the second customer selection event, the first line of code matches (say) 100 rows and the second row matches a different 100 rows. And so on. If I was to run the suggested code, it will match all 5000 rows each time. Or is my thinking completely messed up?

Comment: I do think iterating the dom on page load once and later looking through that array may make life easier. And I know I have said it twice already, but I can't think why Chrome can't handle what IE can. It's like Perman defeating Superman. :-(

Comment: @Abhilash - but you don't understand.  In order to match zero rows, the first jQuery selector has to get every single row in the table and examine it, only to determine that there are none of interest.  Then, your second line of code goes and gets all those rows all over again from scratch.  So you're retrieving and examining every single row twice, once to determine there are not rows to add the `special_hide` class to and then again to find the rows to remove it from.  My code at least examines every single row only once.

Comment: @Abhilash - if you have sample HTML to test against, a jsPerf will show you how much faster a single iteration is.

Comment: Tried it, but it didn't make a difference. Works, but as slow as before on Chrome. Again, IE gets it right, and as you said, it is faster than before due to the single pass

Comment: If the comment above didn't seem clear, I DID see an improvement in speed. But only on IE, not on Chrome

Comment: @Abhilash - If Chrome didn't get faster, then something else is causing the performance problem on Chrome.  It isn't very productive for us to guess without a test environment to run tests in and see the actual HTML and actual code.

Comment: @Abhilash - I just fixed a couple typos in my code samples that could have also been causing problems and added a few more optimizations.

Comment: jfriend00, I noticed the typos and fixed them in my code. Couldn't fix in your comment. Also, your code coupled with Ohgodwhy's suggestions did the trick. No stylesheet switching anymore. Things are all working as expected across all browsers. Thanks for all the help